# Exact calculating the multiply of two real

Tags: precision-and-accuracy

As the machine calculate,the exact calculating with real number have some problem to puzzle me long time.We know the `0.142*0.36523=0.05186266` is exactly equalized in math.But use `Mathematica` to calculate it

```
0.142*0.36523
```

> 0.0518627

We cannot get the exact result,Then

```
SetAccuracy[0.142*0.36523, 20]
```

> 0.05186265999999999793

It cannot get the exact value either.Then

```
0.142`20*0.36523`20
```

> 0.05186266000000000000

Or

```
1.5456343578962`40*1.7894567452416578`40
```

> 2.765845827414613698402608320360000000000

Oh,we get it.So is there a more smart solution to exact calculate the real number rather than add a `` `n `` after every real number?

Comment: enter them as rationals, `142/1000`.  I think if you search you'll find this question has been discussed extensively.

Comment: This seems to be more a question about computer machine double precision binary arithmetic than about Mathematica per se.

Comment: Evidently the old expression "garbage-in, garbage-out" is unknown to younger people today. Well, it still holds and this is good example. Low precision numbers can not be made to produce high-precision results by any algorithm.

Comment: @m_goldberg Thanks point out that.

Answer (score 4):

What you *think* is 0.142 isn't, and what you *think* is 0.36523 isn't either. Those numbers cannot be represented exactly as binary fractions, and so are only approximated in their machine real representations when they are stored. The answer you are getting is as close as the machine can get with 53-bit binary fractions.

To see how far they are off, you can multiply out the mantissa by bringing the machine number into the range [0.5,1) by multiplying or dividing by powers of 2, and then multiply by $2^{53}$. Then you can compare with the rational version of your decimal number:

```
Round[2^55 0.142]/2^55 - 142/1000 // N
```

> ```
> -1.26565*10^-17
> ```

```
Round[2^54 0.36523]/2^54 - 36523/100000 // N
```

> ```
> -9.05942*10^-19
> ```

Answer (score 3):

```
0.142*0.36523

(*  0.0518627  *)
```

The default displayed precision is six digits (menu `Mathematica | Preferences... | Appearance | Numbers | Displayed precision`). If you wish to see additional digits then change this default or use [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm.html)

```
% // InputForm

(*  0.05186266  *)
```

However, in general if you want exact values then you need to use exact numbers (e.g., [`Rationalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html)).

Comment: Change the `Preference` to 40 then `1.5456343578962*1.7894567452416578` will get `2.765845827414614`,and the `InputForm` get `2.765845827414614` too.

Comment: `Rationalize` is very convenient when multiply by two real number with short number of digit after decimal point.But the long digit like `1.5456343578962` will be not suitable.

Comment: @yode - `InputForm` cannot make up digits. If you do a machine precision calculation you will get a machine precision result. `Rationalize` will work with any number if you set the `dx` to zero.  `(1.5456343578962 // Rationalize[#, 0] &) (1.7894567452416578 // 
    Rationalize[#, 0] &) // N[#, 40] &` evaluates to `2.765845827414613818326928016588592905558`

Comment: You can see [this](http://7xpolf.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/11.png)

Comment: @yode - your link is blocked by my virus software as a malicious site.

Comment: Oh~God.It's safe.As same to be `Imgur` site,but the `imgur` is slow in China.

Comment: The period at the end of a sentence should always be followed by a space.